# form:checkoxes with ID throws numberformat exception

Tags: spring, forms

I was trying an example which shows list of books with checkbox for each book.
by using 
`<form:form name="saveTosession" modelAttribute="book">`

`<form:checkboxes items="${book.allBooks}"  path="selectedBooks"/>`

`</form:form>`

Here book object is backing object. Here if I see view source of my JSP, it shows the id for each checkbox as selectedBooks1, selectedBooks2 etc.
But I want the ID be like --

When I tried to include     **ID** attribute for     **form:checkboxes** as     **id="chk_${book.allBooks.isbn}"** getting exception pasted below.

NOTE: I have getter and setter for isbn paramater in my Book class and it is of type int. Any help is appreciated. thanks

it throws exception as

root cause:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "isbn"
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this ??? :(